# Laravel subfolder htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite, laravel-4

I am trying to run laravel in a subfolder on my site and am having trouble with the htaccess portion.

I have seen many questions like this on here, but I haven't found any that apply to my case, or that work fully.

My folder structure is several levels deep:

```
site root/folder1/folder2/laravel installation/public folder/
```

I have been trying to redirect laravel install folder to the public folder, I have done this before when laravel is installed in the root using htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(folder1/folder2/laravel installation/)
/folder1/folder2/laravel installation/public folder/
```

When I put in a blank test index file into the public folder, the code above works and it redirects to it.

However when I use the laravel index file i get the following laravel error:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161
```

If i remove the htaccess and navigate to the public folder directly laravel works (this is a fresh install of laravel).

Is there something I need to change in the laravel config files in order to get this to work? Or is this not possible?

Thank you.

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention that I have an htaccess file in my public folder, here is the code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also, when I type the following url in the site does work, however it forces the index.php. I believe that is because of the rewrite rule I just added, however without this script the site fails to load like before.

```
www.demo.[mydomain].com/folder1/folder2/laravel/index.php
```

Comment: What is the exact route you're using to access the index.php? Cause as far as I know you can't just go to http://localhost/index.php. This probably means you don't have the route you're accessing defined in routes.php

Comment: this is a blank install of laravel so the route is '/'. The url I am pointing to does not contain index.php, I am just point to the folder but it is not directly off the root. I am testing this in a subdomain on a site of mine, the url is: www.demo.[mydomain].com/folder1/folder2/laravel/. The route is the default for laravel 5, which is: Route::get('/', function() { return View('welcome'); }); But I have also tried just returning a string and I still get the same http not found.

Comment: I just discovered though that if i type index.php after the url it does work! See edit in bottom of question

Comment: Try defining your route as that folder structure instead. I don't think laravel is playing well with the subfolders. Instead of trying to trick laravel into using www.domain.com/path/to/my/app/, just tell laravel where you want it to go in the routes.php file